# how to use bootstrap links that is mentioned in the documentation to include in html

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i have added all the needed CDN to make `bootstrap` work in my HTML project ..

```html
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.8/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-I7E8VVD/ismYTF4hNIPjVp/Zjvgyol6VFvRkX/vR+Vc4jQkC+hVqc2pM8ODewa9r" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-fbbOQedDUMZZ5KreZpsbe1LCZPVmfTnH7ois6mU1QK+m14rQ1l2bGBq41eYeM/fS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>    <script src="{% static 'js/theMap.js' %}"></script> 
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

but am getting this error when i run :

```
GET https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.8/dist/umd/popper.min.js net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
/en/web_app/:418 
        
        
        GET https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
/en/web_app/:419 
        
        
        GET https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
```

despite am using the same urls used at the bootstrap official documentation

Comment: The urls are valid. The "ERR_CONNECTION_RESET" appears when the browser fails to connect to a resource. Aren't you connected to some company network with firewall that blocks cdn.jsdelivr.net?

Comment: The error "ERR_CONNECTION_RESET" indicates a problem connecting to the CDN servers hosting Bootstrap and Popper.js files. To resolve it, you can try these steps:

Check your internet connection.
Clear your browser cache.
Use a different network or device.
Verify the CDN status for any known issues.
Consider hosting the files locally if the issue persists.
Connection reset errors are usually temporary and trying again later might resolve the problem.

Comment: `https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/` domain is blocked in a [number of countries](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76643926/22152755).

Answer (score 0):

Add all the links as added in the below code.
Hope this will solve your problem
code cradit: [w3school](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_default&stacked=h)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="jumbotron text-center">
  <h1>My First Bootstrap Page</h1>
  <p>Resize this responsive page to see the effect!</p> 
</div>
  
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <h3>Column 1</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit...</p>
      <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris...</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <h3>Column 2</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit...</p>
      <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris...</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <h3>Column 3</h3>        
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit...</p>
      <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris...</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```